# Symfony2 routing & twig

Tags: symfony, routes, twig, fosuserbundle

I need to include href to `profile/edit` in my view. Template engine is twig, so code look like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile') }}">Edit profile</a>
```

But i get exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "fos_user_profile" as such route does not exist.") in VputiUserBundle:ProfileShow:show.html.twig at line 4.
```

Please help, where is mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, debug your router

```
$ php app/console router:debug --env=[env]
```

And use the correct environment

If the route shows up, then you probably need to clear the cache

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=[env]
```

If the route *doesn't* show up, then whatever bundle that provides that route isn't being loaded correctly.

Also, if you're using a front-controller with debugging turned on, you can check the [web debug toolbar](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#using-the-web-debug-toolbar).

Comment: Here is the route, `fos_user_profile_edit             ANY      ANY    ANY  /profile/edit ` , but after cleaning cache login, registration form is invisible. help me

Answer (score 0):

The message tells it all. Route with name `fos_user_profile` does not exist.

I guess this route name comes from FOSUserBundle, so check that VputiUserBundle extends it properly.

Comment: `class VputiUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

The `path('fos_user_profile')` does not exist. It routes to `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml`. There you can find the actual usable routes, like:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}">Edit profile</a>
```

Comment: Yes, i find that after use : `php app/console router:debug --env=[env]`